# How to run iPython Notebook as a service

Tags: macos, launchd

What would be the best "standard" way to create a `launchd` script to run `python notebook`?

I would like the service to start at login and an easy to start-stop-restart the server from a terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I created the following .plist file. It is autoloaded on startup and it will start a `jupiter` notebook and keep it alive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
      <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
          <key>KeepAlive</key>
          <true/>
          <key>Label</key>
          <string>cern.chernals.ipython</string>
          <key>ProgramArguments</key>
          <array>
              <string>/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook</string>
          </array>
          <key>RunAtLoad</key>
          <true/>
          <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
          <string>/Users/chernals/Library/LaunchAgents/jupyter-notebook.stderr</string>
          <key>StandardOutPath</key>
          <string>/Users/chernals/Library/LaunchAgents/jupyter-notebook.stdout</string>
              <key>KeepAlive</key>
              <true/>
      </dict>
      </plist>
```

Comment: I've written a script that configures a launchagent like this automatically. Check it out [here](http://nathanielobrown.com/blog/posts/trick_to_keep_jupyter_always_running_in_the_background_on_macos.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a macOS newbie, and found the accepted answer very helpful. I modified it to not launch a browser at startup and also start in the directory ~/jupyter where I store most of my notebooks.

For future reference, the way to make this start is to put the xml data in a file in the directory ~/Library/LaunchAgents, e.g. ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.jupyter.notebook.plist.

The plist I ended up with was the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.jupyter.notebook</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook</string>
        <string>--no-browser</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/rickard/Library/LaunchAgents/org.jupyter.notebook.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/rickard/Library/LaunchAgents/org.jupyter.notebook.stdout</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/rickard/jupyter</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I haven't figured out a way to not have to hard code the user's home directory in there -- the EnableGlobbing option only works in ProgramArgument, and there is no environment variable expansion, so for now it needs to be in there.